# Google maps Places request return only one place

Tags: angular, google-maps, google-places-api

I need to get different places from their name and position, I'm using Angular 6 and the PlacesService from google maps.

Here is what I do :

```
from(this._mapsApiLoader.load()).subscribe(() => {
    const service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(document.createElement('div'));
    service.findPlaceFromQuery({
      query: this.search,
      fields: ['geometry', 'name', 'formatted_address'],
      locationBias: new Coordinates(position[0], position[1])
    }, (results) => {

      this._ngZone.run(() => {
        if (results !== undefined
            && results !== null
            && results.length > 0
        ) {

          console.log(results);
        }
      });
    });
  });
```

My problem is that the request only return ONE place, instead of all the places at the coordinates. I also try to put the city instead of the coordinates but still only one place.

Here is an example of the result I get :

```
[{…}]
  0: {formatted_address: "26 Rue du Dr Mazet, 38000 Grenoble, France", geometry: {…}, name: "IKKS Retail", html_attributions: Array(0)}
  length: 1
  __proto__: Array(0)
```

I always get only one, even in cities where there are more than 10 stores

And when I search for the same thing on google maps there is more than one place, how can I get all of theses ?

**EDIT:**

I try to use textSearch instead of findPlaceFromQuery :

```
service.textSearch({
      query: this.search,
      location: new google.maps.LatLng(position[0], position[1]),
      radius: 5000,
    }, ...
```

I can now get multiple results but some results are really outside of the radius, I got one result at 30km from the location with this radius of 5000 meters.

Comment: Can you please post a log of `results`.

Comment: I edit my question